# how to define array in php like array1[] array2[] using for loop

Tags: php, arrays

How to define array in php like `array1[] array2[]` using for loop like instead of `a1` or `a2` I can write ai and its in for loop is it possible?

Like

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
     $ai[$i]="hello'";
}
```

so I would like to say as like

```
a1[1]=Hello
```

Comment: For the sake of code sanity please refrain from doing this, ever.

Comment: Don't do this!  Just `$a[$i][]` or something if you must.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems being unclear and leading already to confusing answers too. Perhaps try to write your question detailed in your own language and translate it with http://translate.google.com or https://www.bing.com/translator. Please edit the question then instead of adding the translation as comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables dynamically using this:

```
${"a$i"}[$i] = 'hello';
```

Comment: how to declare this variable or intialize?

Comment: Why do you want to create variables dynamically?

Comment: Its need of the project

Comment: Are you 100% sure you need dynamic vars? Can't you put the data in an array?

Comment: yes please mention

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a dynamic var

```
 $ai.$i[$i] = 'Hello';
```

or

```
 $ai.$i[$your_index] = 'Hello';
```

but be careful when doing this  .. in this case it is difficult to keep in control of the variables .. is easy to make a mistake

Comment: how to intialize or declare this array?

Comment: your comnment  have not sense .. if you want  a dinamic var ....

Comment: @RiggsFolly  .. thanks for answer  (right) editing

Comment: My Pleasure bro